# viewstate not work and not disable it

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

```
property curRefID:

   public string curRefID
    {
        get
        {
            return  ViewState ["curid"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState ["curid"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I init it in method InitUCControl()

```
   protected override void OnInit ( EventArgs e )
        {
            base.OnInit ( e );
            if ( !IsPostBack )
            {
                InitUCControl ( );
            }
        }
```

and then i want use the property in a button click event,
it always   return null. but it had a value when i debug it in InitUCControl().
    I don't know why it can't  work...so weird. ps:I didn't disable
    viewstate .in page's html source code viewstate can be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) viewstate isn't available in `OnInit` event, try `PreLoad` event instead.